# Laravel Homstead - Only showing server 502 error instead of Laravel error

Tags: php, laravel, nginx

I switched my application to use Laravel Homestead. Everything works great! However, now instead of showing me errors as they come about it is only showing me a 502 bad gateway from the nginx server. Is there a setting or something I could use to make sure it shows me the error via the Laravel error handler? It's impossible to test my issues if it's not showing me an error.

I have debug set to "true" and I am not sure what other information I can provide to help since it works fine on my local apache setup.

Comment: Post the configuration of your Homestead.yaml file. Also try destroying and rebuilding the virtual machine. Are you able to get other Laravel apps running on the box or can't get anything to serve properly?

Comment: Have u enabled display errors in php.Is it showing any errors in apache?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add two lines to Nginx configuration file `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

```
http {
  ...
  fastcgi_buffers 8 16k;
  fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
  ...
}
```

And restart nginx server :)

Comment: sudo systemctl restart nginx

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your storage folder is writeable and belongs to the right user.

Use:

```
 chmod -R 755 storage
```

Comment: I get the same thing. i do have barryvdh debugbar installed. Not sure if that would effect it.

Comment: I also tried composer update to see if that would help but it didn't.

Comment: The debugbar needs also writing rights to the storage folder. What is the user and the rights of the storage map right now? (ls -ltra)

Answer (score 0):

If writable, you should find more info in `app/storage/log/laravel.log`

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue recently after upgrading my Homestead box to 7.0.0

The fix ended up being disabling xdebug as apparently there is a compatibility issue with PHP 7.3

Try this in homestead `sudo phpdismod xdebug`

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting the 502 instead of the Laravel errors make sure the APP_KEY .env variable is set. run `php artisan key:generate` and then try again. When the app goes to render an error it needs a key set or it breaks.
This error can be caused by a bunch of different things. If this doesn't work try the rest of the things suggested in this post.